# How do I go about solving this derivative of inverse tangent?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, inverse

Okay so I have $$f(x)=8\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-\ln \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$$ since $$8\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\tan^{-1}(x)=8\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$would $$8\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=8\left(\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}\right)\text{ ??}$$  If not, how do I go about finding the derivative? Please if it's not right, show me step by step how to get the derivative so that I can fully grasp the process. Thanks in advance!! EDIT: SORRY I CHANGED THE NOTATION.

Comment: is $y$ a constant?

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong notation @Alex.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851001/how-do-i-solve-this-trig-derivative-in-respect-to-x

Comment: Definitely you should apply the identity that tells you that $\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \frac 1 2 \log(x^2+y^2)$ before differentiating.  It's needlessly complicated otherwise.  And use the chain rule.  You could also apply the trigonometric identity that says $\tan^{-1}(y/x)=\pi/2 - \tan^{-1}(x/y)$ before differentiating.  That makes it a little bit simpler, but not immensely so.  And use the chain rule there too.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'm not fully understanding how to apply that to $$8\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\tan^{-1}(x)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\tan^{-1} \left(\frac yx\right)\right) = \frac 8{1+\left(\frac yx\right)^2}\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\frac yx\right)$$

(You forgot to use the chain rule (see the last factor in the product on the right, above.) Recall that $$\frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1}(g(x)) = \frac 1{1 + (g(x))^2} \cdot g'(x)$$
Here, $$g(x) = \frac yx \implies g'(x) = \frac {-y}{x^2}$$

---

For the second term, use a nice property of logarithms:

$$\ln\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \ln(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2} = \frac 12 \ln(x^2 + y^2)$$

Now, when differentiating the second term, don't forget the chain rule for this term too. $$\frac d{dx}\left(\frac 12 \ln(x^2 + y^2)\right) = \frac 12\cdot \dfrac 1{x^2 + y^2}\cdot \frac d{dx}\left(x^2 + y^2\right)$$

And remember, $y$ is being used as a constant.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I will try it now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, Kenshin!

Comment: Thanks, @Sami Indeed I follow the World Cup ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is a constant, treat it as a constant! For the first term you'll get 
$$
\frac{-\frac{y}{x^2}}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^2}
$$

EDIT: for the second term use the property $\log x^a = a \log x $ and then apply the chain rule.

Comment: do you think what he means is actually $\tan ^{-1}(\frac{f(x)}{x})$?

Comment: . . . and remember that $\dfrac{-y/x^2}{1 +(y/x)^2} = \dfrac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @amWhy Sorry I changed it to $$\frac{d}{dx}$$.

Comment: And don't forget that the first term is multiplied by the constant $8$.

Comment: OK so $y$ is a constant then, my hint is correct.

Comment: @Alex So your answer would work whilst solving $$\frac{d}{dx}%%, right? I'm sorry. I'm not to good at this math stuff haha.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, my solution 'will work' if $y$ is a constant.